# Left Join query in BigQuery keeps getting error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I´m trying to do a left join on 2 tables (Tasks, Projects) however I keep getting this error:

> Cannot access field id on a value with type ARRAY> at [4:17]

I´ve already tried with a different keys like:

```
ON ( t.projects.gid=p.id )
```

but the trouble persists

The Query is as follows:

```
SELECT 

from `dashboards-sur.asana_conversion.tasks`as t

LEFT JOIN `dashboards-sur.asana_conversion.projects` as p

ON ( t.projects.id=p.id )
```

What I expect is to add the data from the project table into the Tasks table

Answer (score 0):

You have to unnest values in array first. Not sure what your schema is but I guess SQL should be like this:

```
select * from
(
    SELECT t.*, p.id
    from dashboards-sur.asana_conversion.tasksas t, unnest(projects) as p
)
LEFT JOIN dashboards-sur.asana_conversion.projects as p
using(id)
```

[official docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays)

Comment: The schema is as follows   TABLE1= Tasks    KEY = projects.id     TABLE 2 = Projects Key=id

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can approach this.  I would probably go for:

```
SELECT t.*, p.*
FROM dashboards-sur.asana_conversion.tasksas t LEFT JOIN
     dashboards-sur.asana_conversion.projects as p
     ON p.id IN (SELECT pid FROM UNNEST(t.projects.id) pid);
```

I prefer this to using `UNNEST()` in the outer `FROM` clause because you are using `LEFT JOIN`.  This will return rows that have no projects.

If you do put this in the outer `FROM`, you can use:

```
SELECT t.*, p.*
FROM dashboards-sur.asana_conversion.tasksas t LEFT JOIN
     UNNEST(t.projects.id) pid
     ON 1 = 1 LEFT JOIN
     dashboards-sur.asana_conversion.projects as p
     ON p.id = pid;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your table is in array format, you need to "normalize" data in order to query. I suggest using the column `event_params` like "key".

For example, the event_params column has the columns `event_params.key`,  `event_params.value.string_value`, `event_params.value.int_value` and etc

I had the same problem and you can make the query as follows:

```sql
SELECT
  A.event_timestamp,
  B.time_stamp
FROM
  `id-projeto.conjunto-de-dados.table` AS A
JOIN
  UNNEST (event_params) AS event_params
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    event_timestamp AS time_stamp
  FROM
    `id-projeto.conjunto-de-dados.table`
  JOIN
    UNNEST (event_params) AS event_params) AS B
ON
  A.event_timestamp = B.time_stamp
```